# tcpdump: how to see source and destination of HE_MU packets?

Tags: wifi, tcpdump, wireshark

I'm currently testing a router and trying to capture HE_MU packets.

For this I have a setup with 5 end-user devices and a device that acts as a packet sniffer and also hosts iperf3 servers.

I put the wireless network interface of the sniffer device into monitoring mode with "sudo airmon-ng start wlo1 128" and set its frequency "sudo iw dev wlo1mon set freq 5640 80MHz".

Then I open 5 iperf3 server ports on the sniffer device and connect all the other devices with them and have them send UDP packets and after that I start a tcpdump capture with "sudo tcpdump -i wlo1mon -c 10000000 -w tcpdumpoutput".

I analyze the output in wireshark and can find HE_MU packets, which is good, but I can't see the source or destination of those HE_MU packets, which is bad. I also capture a lot of HE_SU packets and those have a source and destination.

So I was wondering if someone knows why the HE_MU packets have no source and destination and also if someone knows how to change/fix that. Are there any flags/arguments I've missed or steps that I haven't done but need to do?
Every help is much appreciated!

Comment: hint: paragraphs make your question more palatable to read - I got as far as the first sentence and couldn't be bothered